# How can I do a Interprocess communication in C# when process can come and go?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ipc

I have 2 process WriterProc and ReaderProc.

WriterProc only writes and ReaderProc only reads. I can use named pipes for communication but the problem is ReaderProc may not be alive when writer is writing it or vice-versa.

Both can be active at the same time so synchronization between writes and reads may be required.

What would be suggested way in c# 4?

Comment: What kind of data is read/written?

Comment: So you're looking for some kind of "persistant IPC"? Use files IMO *or* a proxy between the reader and the writer.

Answer (score 2):

[Message Queuing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms711472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) services are designed for use in situations like yours. They provide guaranteed message delivery, so if the writer was busy writing while the reader was not running, the reader would find a queue full of messages after starting up.

Comment: can we use something lower level like MappedFiles?

Comment: @Rohit with anything at a lower level you would end up re-implementing the functionality of persistent messages, which is very hard to get right, given the many exceptional situations that you might see (reader crashes, writer crashes, computer reboots, to name just a few). You certainly can communicate through memory-mapped files, or even through regular files. But the number of synchronization issues that you'd need to consider in order to achieve guaranteed delivery is overwhelming.

Answer (score 0):

How about making them WCFs.

The writer WCF will signal Reader WCF to stop reading when it is about to read and then signal once writing is done.